# Just Trying To Be Helpful

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My First is a masculine flower pot.
>   My Second a joint, but smoke it not.
>   My Third is a swimmer, of sea or stream.
>   My Last is a mound, grassy and green.
>
> Put me together and confused you may be,
>   But speak me out loud and soon you will see.
>   I'm good for all without omission.
>   So I'm good for you by definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are

> BENEFICIAL -- which is to say helpful and doing good, hence the title and second stanza.

My First is a masculine flower pot.

> BEN from the old children's TV programme "Bill and Ben, the Flowerpot Men".

My Second a joint, but smoke it not.

> KNEE.

My Third is a swimmer, of sea or stream.

> FISH.

My Last is a mound, grassy and green.

> HILL.

Comment: (I was hung up for a while trying to make it rot13(ORARSNPGBE) with rot13(GBE nf gur gur tenffl terra zbhaq).)

Comment: Nice one Gareth! You can't have been hung up for too long, pretty rapid response.

Comment: No, only a couple of minutes, but it _felt_ like a long time because I was expecting someone else to swoop in and solve it quickly if I didn't :-).